# How to solve the error "Error parsing asset file" in advanced_pdf_viewer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and developing a custom app(just for testing). I have bunch of pdfs in `docs` folder. So to view respective pdf, I passed an id to the pdf viewer to load the pdf file from button. When I type the pdf name (static) in `loaddocument()` , it works fine.

*FYI - all pdfs are starting with name of `law` and have integer value in end. for example `law1.pdf`.*

here is the function code.

## LoadPdf

```
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';

loadDocument() async {
      String id= widget.lawid;
      String filename= 'law$id';
      print(filename);
      document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset('docs/law/$filename.pdf');
      setState(() => isLoading = false);
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: isLoading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : PDFViewer(
                  document: document,
                  zoomSteps: 1,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        )),
    ));
  }
```

I got the error when I pass the id from Button. The error is `Error parsing asset file`. I am using `advance_pdf_viewer` package. Please suggest me too if you have any other pdf viewer package. This package doesn't support continuous scroll (it renders one pager per scroll).

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: replace 'docs/law/$filename.pdf' with 'assets/docs/law/$filename.pdf'

Comment: changing only the path effect the work?

Comment: In pubspec.yaml what is your assets dir?